# WIF and ADFS - Requesting for more\extra claims

Tags: wif, adfs

I have a a ASP.NET web site which uses a ADFS 2.0 to provide claims.
On the ADFS I have implemented a Custom Attribute Store. This store goes and gets some particular claims from an old legacy system which can take some time (20 -30sec)

What I would like to know is how to do I only get this claim when required. 
I don't want to get this claim when clients first logon. Its not always required.
How do I go back to the ADFS server and get it to reissue the users claims and add one extra claim?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Darrin

Updated:
Is it possible to send something from the client (ASP.NET page using WSTrustChannel as an active client) to the ADFS server that I can then test for in one of my claim rule conditions?

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET app can be an active client to the STS as well as a passive one. When you need to get the additional claims, use the WSTrustChannelFactory to make a call directly to the STS.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have set up an active client on my asp.net page and tested that it works just fine. I was looking at the RequestTokenSecurity properties and adding a claim of type http://GetSpecialClaims with a value of true. I then tried to check for this claim and value in one of my Rules c:[type == "http://GetSpecialClaims:, Value == "True"] => issue.... But the claim is not part of the incoming claims. Any further suggestions on how to identify that the special claim should be retrieved?